AWS spot interruption notice EventBridge event not being sent on simulation
I'm using Spot instances and have setup an EventBridge rule for spot interruption notices. The target is an SQS queue to which I have a consumer attached.
To test my setup, I've tried manually initiating an interruption. But the issue is there are no events in my EventBridge metrics page nor in my SQS queue. The docs clearly say that this shouldn't be the case. From Initiate a spot instance:

After you initiate the interruption, the following occurs:

...
A Spot Instance interruption notice is issued two minutes before AWS FIS interrupts your instance.
...


How do I test this setup properly? I've tested my consumer by manually pushing a message of the required format to my SQS queue but I need to test the AWS plumbing. Can I simulate interruption notices somehow?
